# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer -java

Tags: java, eclipse

When I tried to run my code on Eclipse IDE, this error keeps on poping up:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <?> at index 24: (path to project).
```

I don't know what this error meant. 
 First, I thought it was some problem caused by some of my own code. But when I tried to run the Hello World program, the same problem existed.

It isn't a problem with Java, because I reinstalled it and the same problem still happens(Plus, when I use the command line tools, the program compiled and ran perfectly fine). It is not that Java can't access my code from a different drive either(I kept my project on the D: drive, not the C: drive), because I moved my project to C:\Users\username\Documents\Eclipse Workspace and the problem still existed. I also tried reinstalling eclipse, but that didn't change anything.

Can anyone tell me what is causing the problem?

Comment: Well the error is pretty accurate in telling whats wrong, the 24s char in the path to your project is an illegal char (one that should not be part of the URL). In this case it's likely a '?', the '<?>' could also be a placeholder for a different byte value with no graphical representation, this however seems unlikely. (probably your username)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this by changing the name of the folder contain the project. In my case, the problem is it didn't understand the path to the project. Just change the folder's name to English.

Answer (score 0):

After I removed the quotes surrounding the path to JavaFX in the run configuration(under eclipse) it worked !

before :
--module-path "C:\JavaFX\javafx-sdk-16\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

after :
--module-path C:\JavaFX\javafx-sdk-16\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml